# Redirecting "if entry is not defined" returns 404 instead

Tags: entry, redirect, routing, 404

All the documentation, and answers here say this should work... But it returns the 404 instead of redirecting and I can't figure out why?

- Section: Structure = help
- Entry URL Format: Top-Level Entries =
  help/{slug}
- Entry URL Format: Nested Entries = help/{slug}
- Entry 'sTemplate = help/_entry

Top line of the "help/_entry.html" template contains

```
{% if entry is not defined %}
    {% redirect "/help/welcome-to-help" 301 %}
{% endif %}
```

where "welcome-to-help" is an Entry slug in the Help Section.

If I hit "example.com/help/welcome-to-help/" *(or any other valid Slug)*, everything works fine. But if I hit "example.com/help/asdf/" it returns the 404 instead of redirecting.

Am at a loss at this point??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting a 404 is because Craft isn't even hitting your `help/_entry.html` template. Because there's no entry matching the URI `/help/asdf`, the template will never render and the request will go straight to 404.

The solution is to create a [dynamic route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) matching your section's URL format (i.e. `help/<slug>`), and point it to the same template.

This works, because whenever Craft can't match a URI to an entry or category, it'll then try to render any dynamic route matching the URI's format (for a deeper understanding of how Craft manages routes and requests, I'd recommend looking at the [the official docs' page on routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing)).

Comment: Thanks so much @Mats. I'm migrating an EE site and in the old site, when a user hit **/help/** I would simply check for value in seg2, and if didn't exist, would specify a specific Entry_ID in the EE Entries tag. That would always display whatever Entry the client wanted at the **/help/** index.

So what I'm now doing in Craft (found in another question here) in these simple Sections is having help/index and help/_entry, where help/index just has a 301 redirect to **/help/valid-index-slug-wanted-by-client**

A bit of a hack but accomplishes what the client wants.